# Using grep for bash outputs

Tags: linux, bash, script, grep

I want find servers that not using "net" command. So, I'll run a script from remote. The script is like that:

```
for ip in $(cat ip_list_file)
do
    netCom=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no $ip "net ads info | grep -i command | wc -l")
    if [ $netCom -eq 1 ]
    then 
        echo -e $ip >> not_installed
    else
        echo -e $ip >> installed
    fi
done
```

But I have a problem at "net ads info | grep -i command | wc -l" command, because I was thinking I can use "bash: net: **command** not found..." sentence but I can't. I don't want reverse my script like find installed. My question is this: How can I use grep command for the outputs like "bash: net: command not found..."?

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). More proper way is to check if the exit code is `127` (see [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)) or to use `type` (bash builtin), e.g. `type -P net`.

Comment: Actually it's not XY problem. But the main problem is more bigger than this. So I just asked this part with some changes. Maybe the example was bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is printed to stderr, so you need to redirect it to stdout instead, in order for grep to find it.

```
for ip in $(cat ip_list_file)
do
    netCom=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no $ip "net ads info 2>&1 | grep -i command | wc -l")
    if [ $netCom -eq 1 ]
    then 
        echo -e $ip >> not_installed
    else
        echo -e $ip >> installed
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of "2>&1"? I can understood redirecting but how is work "2>&1"?

Comment: 2>&1 means roughly "redirect file handle 2 to file handle 1" (2 being stderr and 1 being stdout). So everything written to stderr gets instead written to stdout.